# Dealing with zero log values in R?

Tags: r, graphics, plot, statistics

I am plotting a scatter `plot(x, y)` and want it to be log-valued, so I do: `plot(log(x), log(y))`. I'd like to deal with cases where some value in `x` is 0, and thus not on the plot, while the corresponding `y` value is nonzero.

I'd like to display the scatter with log ticks but natural number values, meaning if in `log2` then the ticks should be `2^0, 2^1, 2^2, ...` that would allow me to plot 0 values on the scale as well so as to not miss these points.

Here's an example:

```
> x = c(0, 1, 20, 100, 200, 500)
> y = c(1, 16, 32, 105, 300, 50)
> plot(x, y)
```

There are six points. If I use:

```
> plot(log2(x), log2(y))
```

There are only 5 plotted, since x[0], y[0] is omitted (the x-value is 0). Therefore, I'd like to plot the log values but have tick labels to be natural numbers that are simply marked on a log scale. Then you can easily have on the same axis, 0, 2^0 (which is 1 of course), 2^1, 2^2, etc. and so on.  Then the point (x[0], y[0]) will **still be plotted**, while keeping the log scale.

Side note: I don't think it's fair to downvote a post asking something very reasonable with an example. This is clearly on topic and relevant, and will come up for virtually everyone who is plotting things on a log value and cares about boundary / edge cases.

(I know some people deal with this by adding an arbitrary small constant to all points but I'd like to avoid that as it is messy.)  thanks

Comment: Example code would be nice. Have you looked at 'log1p()' and 'expm1()'?

Comment: I did give example code. My code is just ``plot(x,y)`` and ``plot(log2(x), log2(y))`` nothing more to it.

Comment: How would including `2^0` on the axis let you include the zero value? `2^0` is 1

Comment: @DavidRobinson: That's not what I said. I said that plotting it with natural scale, 2^0,...,2^N is what would allow me to have 0. If it's a natural scale, the 0 point makes sense. If the values are -1, 0, 1, 2 and are meant to be log2 values, then the 0 point is 1 and therefore the natural number 0 cannot be plotted.

Comment: What do you mean? Where would 0 go on a scale that has 2^0, 2^1, etc? (unless - are these integer values?)

Comment: are `x` and `y` the result of taking the logarithm? Then you don't want to plot the logarithm of the logarithm!

Comment: @user248237: I mean example data or a sample of your data (using dput()).  It makes it easier to reproduce the problems you're having and give appropriate advice.

Comment: There's nothing preventing you from plotting 0 alongside 2^0, 2^1, and yes, of course these are natural numbers.

Comment: I would just use `log1p()` instead, but you seem to think that that's "too messy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you want to plot x versus y in the log scale?

Here and example using `lattice` and `latticeExtra`

```
# Some reproducible data
tm <- data.frame(x=seq(0,10,1),y=seq(0,10,1))
library(lattice) 
library(latticeExtra) 
xyplot(x ~ y , data=tm, 
       scales= list(x=list(log=2), 
                    y=list(log=2)), 
       xscale.components = xscale.components.logpower, ## to get pretty scales
        yscale.components = yscale.components.logpower 
)
```

[image]